# batch file to create directory based on file name, move like files to new directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have hundreds of files in a directory that all have different names but some of those are related.

The files are mostly .AI and PDF and are all names like this:

- FILE1_retail_xxx.ai
- FILE1_label_xxx.ai
- FILE2_retail_xxx.ai
- FILE2_label_xxx.ai
- FILE3_retail_xxx.ai
- FILE3_label_xxx.ai

What I want to do is have a batch file create directories for FILE1, FILE2, FILE3, etc. and move all files that start with FILE1, FILE2, FILE3, etc. into those newly created directories.

I have used this, but it just makes a DIR for the whole filename.

```
@echo off
for %%i in (*) do (
 if not "%%~ni" == "organize" (
  md "%%~ni" && move "%%~i" "%%~ni"
 )
)
```

This doesn't do what I need, can anyone help massage this into what I need or give me a new batch file to try?

Thanks! This will save me countless hours of manual work!

Comment: To do exactly as your question asks, `@For %%# In (1 2 3)Do @"%__AppDir__%Robocopy.exe" . FILE%%# FILE%%#_* /Mov>NUL`. However I'm sure that based upon this you're going to modify or better clarify your question.

Comment: To perform the task how I think you wanted it, `@For %%I In (*)Do @If /I Not "%%I"=="%~nx0" For /F "EOL=_Delims=_" %%# In ("%%~nxI")Do @"%__AppDir__%Robocopy.exe" . "%%#" "%%I" /XF *organize* /Mov>NUL`, should get you somewhere closer. This single line batch file works for all files in the current directory, not just those which contain an underscore. That should be simple enough to account for, should it matter for your specific task.

Answer (score 1):

You need to split the filename by `_` with another `for /f` loop:

```
@echo off
for %%i in (*) do (
  if not "%%~ni" == "organize" ( 
    for /f "delims=_" %%a in ("%%~ni") do (
      md "%%a" 2>nul 
      move "%%~i" "%%~a\" 
  )
)
```

`2>nul` suppresses the error message in case the folder already exists.

Please consider using `for %%i in (*_*) do (` or `for %%i in (*_*_*.ai *_*_*.pdf) do (` - according to your actual needs/file names to pre-select files to be moved.